# how to capture editor data with help of selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, ckeditor, selenium-ide

i am working on one application which have third party editor (ck editor).
I am  not able to record action perform on editor using selenium IDE.
Please suggest me solution so that i can able to record those action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ckeditor library javascript to set the content of a ckEditor instance.  I've used the solution below

```
runScript
CKEDITOR.instances['body'].setData('<p>testContent</p>');
```

change "body" for the name of your ckEditor instance

[image]